# PHP Temp Directory issue

Tags: php, laravel, http, networking, guzzle

I am new to this temp directory thing and managing files on the backend with PHP so any help would be great. So the gist here is that I click to download either one specific file or all of the files. The trick is that depending on a particular condition, the data is coming back from the API as a stream and the other is coming back as the content (in this case html). In my eyes this logic should work. I have the message coming back as either true or false to determine whether it is a stream or if it is the content of the file. But something about the two conditions is breaking. I've managed to get all sorts of cases working. Individually they download fine but then the bulk download breaks or the other way around if I move the code around. Any suggestions?

```
public function downloadTranslations(Request $request, $id)
{
    $target_locales = $request->input("target_locale");
    $has_source = $request->input("source");
    $client = new API(Auth::user()->access_token, ZKEnvHelper::env('API_URL', 'https://myaccount.site.com'));
    $document = Document::find($id);
    $job_document = JobDocument::where('document_id', $id)->first();
    $job = Job::find($job_document->job_id);

    $file = tempnam('tmp', 'zip');
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    $name_and_extension = explode('.', $document->name);

    if($target_locales == null){
        $target_locales = [];
        foreach ($job->target_languages as $target_language) {
            $target_locales[] = $target_language['locale'];
        }
    }
    foreach($target_locales as $target_locale){
        $translation = $client->downloadDocument($document->document_id, $target_locale);
        $stream = Stream::factory($translation->get('body'));
            $filename = $name_and_extension[0] . ' (' . $target_locale . ').' . $name_and_extension[1];
            if($translation->get('message') == 'true') {

                $tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'lingo');

                $handle = fopen($tmpfile, 'w');
                fwrite($handle, $stream->getContents());
                $zip->addFile($tmpfile, $filename);

                fclose($handle);
            }
            else if($translation->get('message') == 'false'){
                $zip->addFromString($filename, $translation->get('body'));
            };
        }
        $translation = $client->downloadDocument($document->document_id, null, null);

        $filename = $name_and_extension[0].  ' (Source).'.$name_and_extension[1];
        $zip->addFromString($filename, $translation->get('body'));
        $zip->close();

    return response()->download($file, $name_and_extension[0].'.zip')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on your code, i don't even know how it doesn't brake:

```
        else if($translation->get('message') == 'false'){
            $zip->addFromString($filename, $translation->get('body'));
        };
```

i don't think that semi-colon is supposed to be there... anyways.

I also see on your code this: `$file = tempnam('tmp', 'zip');`

Check that this function is really creating different values, maybe by returning this string, if not there might be some race condition on the request from your stream.

This is a problem i faced a few weeks ago. Try something like this: addapt my code to your needs..

```php
    $zip_name = 'yourAmazing.zip';
    $zip_path = storage_path('temp/');

    // If the zip path doesnt exist, create it.
    if (!file_exists($zip_path)) {
        File::makeDirectory($zip_path);
        mkdir($zip_path, 666, true);
    }else{
        // Do nothing realy
    }

    // If the zip file already exist, delete it so you don't have problems when trying to create it again and you don't have to validate if each file is on there
    if (file_exists($zip_path . $zip_name)) {
        File::delete($zip_path . $zip_name);
    }

    // create your zip
    $zip = Zip::create($zip_path . $zip_name);
    // add your temp folder files
    $zip->add(storage_path('/temp/folderofyourfiles'));

    $zip->close();

    // DELETE directory where the files where stored, 
    // since they are already on the zip
    File::deleteDirectory(storage_path('/temp/folderofyourfiles'));

    // DELETE AFTER SEND does what it says assuring it delete the temp file
    // However, if the transfer is interrupted, the file wont delete, since the
    // send event was not terminated. Leaving the file there, thats why i check 
    // that the ZIP doesn't exist already
    return response()
           ->download($zip_path . $zip_name, 'The name for your download')
           ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: This might not be the straight answer to your needs, but you might find hints on there to what you need!

Comment: At this point I'll try anything. I've spent way too many days trying to figure this out so I'll definitely try and use your example in a bit. Thanks! @Erubiel

Comment: Check my comments on the last line, i think whats happening to you might be related to this.

Comment: I noticed after I saw your comment that I didn't post the last part of the function so I actually have that part there now that's somewhat similar @Erubiel

Comment: My problem was the following: i had to create some Images with Intervention on a temporary folder, then create a zip. It was working alright, but if the download was interrupted, it started breaking when i try to create and download the same zip. So i fixed it by deleting the temporary folder where i created the images and adding the check for the Zip before even creating it. And it worked... This code is the last part of the function, after i created all the files

Comment: do you think setting a timeout before I return the zip to download on the front end would be telling of that being the issue in this case?